# C# go to line on word click?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

So I've tried googling this but it hasn't come back with anything useful or at least not anything that would help with this particular scenario.
Essentially what I would like to do is have a word in a richtexbox which is linked to a line elsewhere in the same richtextbox so that when a user clicks the word they are taken to the associated line.

I've considered storing an array of every linked word with its index and length that gets searched each time the user navigates the textbox and scrolls to the linked line number when selected but this doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: is the data in the textbox static or is it dynamic?

Comment: Well you can edit it but if I can just get it to work statically for the moment without considering text changes that would be fine.

Comment: There is a linkclicked event  if you could turn your keywords into links perhaps you can go that way, but the richtextbox recognizes links on its own, so you would have to www.keyword.com them all which would cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the richtextbox doesn't support anything like that out of the box, so your suggestion is actually a good way to go. To improve performance, you can use a dictionary to look up the selected link. The performance hit shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Ok, could you suggest a custom control which would support this?

Comment: @Twisted89 - I'm afraid I'm not aware of any. Not that I've looked. :P Check out Devexpress, Telerik and Infragistics - they're the manufacturers of some of the best controls around, if you can afford it. Perhaps one of them has it. If not... well, you're on your own. :( Google or write it yourself. Also, a slightly crazy option is to use something like CKEditor, hosted inside a browser control. A browser supports links like that - but I strongly suspect that the performance will be a lot worse than the simple workaround you described yourself, not to mention the work involved...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll see what I can find!